# Child element not inheriting height from parent table cell in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, standards-compliance

I have the following [scenario](http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/gqLUw/3/), where I have a table that is to take up 100% height:

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td class="fixed">
            Fixed height row
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table2"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Content
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inside the table cell I have some other element that I want to fill the parent table cell height (100%).

This works in IE Quirks mode (which the original application was written against), as well as Chrome and Safari. I haven't checked other browsers.

However it doesn't seem to work in any version of IE in standards mode. It seems that the child element does not implicitly inherit the height of its parent table cell.

Is this an IE bug, and what is the best way to work around it?

*Additional Information:*

*This scenario is widespread throughout an enormous legacy enterprise application that we are trying to make standards compliant. Therefore I'm looking for a solution that involves the least amount of changes possible to the markup.*

Comment: is there any reason why you are using tables? tables are for tabular data (if you are wanting the code to be more compliant you should remove the tables that are used for formatting), if you are just wanting a fixed height header it can easily be achieved with divs

Comment: Also which versions of ie does it need to be compatible with?

Comment: @Pete as I said in my question we are dealing with an enormous legacy application. I know tables for layout are bad, but that's just the way it is in this case. We are trying to make the application multi-browser and this issue could potentially create us a LOT of work. Changing the layout structure for every page would be years worth of development!

Comment: Any solution would only need to be compatible with IE9+ if that helps at all.

Comment: not sure if you need the second tables content vertical aligned but if you don't you could [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/gqLUw/23/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is evident in both IE and Firefox.

The latter being [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10212) as a bug since 1999.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make positioned... i.e parent and child position et to :relative and absolute respectively

Comment: I have tried making the cell position:relative and absolutely positioning the child top:0 bottom:0, which if you were to try you will see does not work.

Answer (score -2):

Give your table cells a height of 100%.

```
td{height:100%;}
```

See updated fiddle in IE http://jsfiddle.net/gqLUw/11/

Comment: This causes the second row to overflow the container.

Comment: Do you have a different solution?

Comment: If I did I wouldn't be asking here! Your solution swaps one problem for another.